# The type or namespace name 'ConnectionOptions' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wmi

```
Error 2 The type or namespace name 'ConnectionOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Service\App_Code\PService.cs    55  10  C:\...\Service\
```

when trying to use  the code in

```
 [WebMethod]
 public ConnectionOptions remoteconnection(string MyComputerName, string ip)
 {
     ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();

     return connOptions ;

 }
```

While the same code when copied in webApplication gives no error.I have included using system.Management in both the files..

Comment: Did you also add a **reference** in your web service project to `System.Management`?  Adding a using statement isn't enough - the project has to have a reference to it as well.

Comment: @Tim I have added Reference under .NET category in webApplication but i exactly dont know how to add reference in webservice please guide me with a relevant link or more informarion..

Comment: is your web service in its own project or is it in the same project as your web application?  If its in its own project you would add the reference the same way you did in your web application.  If it's in the same project as your web app, then something else is going - possibly a misspelling in your using statement (remember C# is case-sensitive).

Comment: Its in the same project as WebApp..But when i write the same code in webapplication it does not display error message..so i guess it isnt a misspell..

Comment: Hmm....two things to come to mind.  1.  Is there a typo in your using?  2.  Is the webservice in a different namespace (I don't think that would cause a problem, but it doesn't hurt to eliminate it as a potential issue).

Answer (score 1):

You define namespace of System.Managment but that’s no enough. Definning simply let
you access class without full name (using namespace). To enable ASP.NET
to know type a reference to the assembly that holds that type is
necessary. Add reference by using "Add reference" sub menu under
"project" menu.
And then check System.Management item and add the reference your project.